# How to sort files by last modified time using stat -c '%n%Y'? (BASH)

Tags: bash, unix

I would like to sort the files of a directory using `stat -c %n%Y <directory_path>*`, this command gives you the name of the file concatenated with the time of last modification. Problem is that I don't know how to take last number characters (last modification time) in order to sort the files with a pipe, I guess it would be something like this  `stat -c %n%Y <directory_path>* | sort`, I have already read stat and sort mannuals and other filter mannuals like find or cut and I still don't have a solution. Any suggestions are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please show what your input data looks like, what you've tried, your intended results, and especially what version of unix you are running. The `stat` command works differently in your operating system than in mine; `-c` is not a valid option for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you separate the file and time with a space then you can sort the second column using `-k 2`:

```
rseaman@Ubuntu-PC:~/temp/20180310/49211913$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rseaman rseaman  0 Mar 10 18:42 file0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rseaman rseaman 37 Mar 10 18:10 file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rseaman rseaman 22 Mar 10 18:10 file2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rseaman rseaman 19 Mar 10 18:13 file3
rseaman@Ubuntu-PC:~/temp/20180310/49211913$ stat -c "%n %Y" * | sort -n -k 2
file1 1520705401
file2 1520705411
file3 1520705612
file0 1520707323
```

You can then remove the space afterwards if you wish with `| tr -d ' '`, but this will interfere with files which have a space in them.

Answer (score 0):

you can list the files in directory (sorted by modify time) with a simple command:

```
ll -trh
```

OR

```
ls -ltrh
```

-t     sort by modification time

-r     reverse order while sorting

-h     with -l, print sizes in human readable format